# how do I report my wife's 1042-s when filing jointly after she's made the election to be treated as resident alien 6013(g)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, international

My wife is a G4 visa holder and an employee of an international organization. She has a bank account ([UNFCU](https://www.unfcu.org/form-1042S/))  in the US where she receives interests. The bank issues 1042-s and not 1099-int. Last year we were married and we are filing jointly and electing for her to be treated as a resident alien under section 6013(g).
How do I report the interest received from 1042-S?

Comment: On the joint return as interest income -- usually line 2b but Schedule B if you have a lot of interest or special conditions apply, see [pub 550 "How to Report Interest"](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2019_publink100010042). If there was withholding (usually not for interest) report on line 25c and if you file on paper (which I never recommend and especially not during COVID) attach copy C to your return. If you use software you'll probably have to falsely enter that you got 1099-INT and give the amount(s) as it(they) would have appeared on that form.